# How do I move files from one folder to another based on a substring of their names?

Tags: linq

Folder 1:

C:\File1-xpt
C:\File1-ppt
C:\File1-zzz
C:\File2-ndo
C:\File2-dkl
C:\File2-dlz

string[] AllFilesInDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(SelectedDirectory);

I want to move all files with prefix "File1" into Folder 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = AllFilesInDirectory.Where(x => Path.GetFileName(x).StartsWith("File1"));
foreach (string file in query)
{
    File.Move(file, @"C:\Folder2");
}
```

EDIT:
Based on comment.  If know only the substring, you can use `Contains`.  Note the using of `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`, as this will be able to deal with file names like "txtFile1.txt" and "File1.txt" if you were searching for files that contained "txt" (in this case, only the first file would match)

```
var query = AllFilesInDirectory
           .Where(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x).Contains("File1"));
foreach (string file in query)
{
    File.Move(file, @"C:\Folder2");
}
```

Comment: hmmmm it says cannot create file that already exists. not sure why, this file does not exist in folder2

Comment: also, what if i dont know what "startswith" is ? all I know is the substring portion of it?